# same php session name

Tags: php, session

I have two same php website(website A and B). The website as below.

php website

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

  echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user'];

}else{

  if(isset($_POST['userName'])){

    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];

  }

}

?>
```

I post a value userName=Bear to A website by html form. 
After i open the B website with `same browser`, it will output this
Welcome Bear

B website session `is not set`. But B still got A website session.
`A website and B website in same computer`.

How i can fix it? 
Except change the session name or change browser. 
Are there other ways to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this in the same browser? It's going to be very tough having two different sessions open in the same browser, if not impossible. What is your specific context here, why is this an issue?

Comment: Try two separate browsers.

Comment: This wouldn't work with the same browser unless you randomize the session name each time someone signs in. That's not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT #2

Try this then. This will check if the session is set and not empty.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && (!empty($_SESSION['user']))){ 
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user'];
}

else {
echo "Sorry you do not have access.";
}
?>
```

Assuming your form resembles this:

```
<form method="post" action="session_file.php">
     Username: <input type="text" name="userName">
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

---

### OLD

As per your [**original question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20821972/revisions)

---

`sesstion_start();` is misspelled

Use `session_start();`

Plus you missed a semi-colon in `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName']`

Another reason is that you didn't assign your POST username to a SESSION name.

I.e.: (which I added below)

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];
```

**PHP** (session_file.php) as per the HTML form action below

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];

echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user'];

}else{

if(isset($_POST['userName'])){

$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userName'];

}

}

// var_dump($_SESSION['user']); // for testing purposes

?>
```

### EDIT (added `session_destroy()` if one exists already)

In conjunction with the following HTML form (PHP)

If a session already exists, for example `Bear` using the form below as shown, will not show it, because it will check if a session already exists, and if one does exist, it will destroy it and create a new one, which will echo the new name on the next page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
session_destroy();
}
?>

<form method="post" action="session_file.php">
     Username: <input type="text" name="userName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>">
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, But this is not the php program's problem. Assume the php program is work.

Comment: You're welcome, but did you try my code above? @user3143168 If you have more code to show me, I will need to see it.

Comment: If you don't want account `B` to see account `A` as `Bear` then you will need to destroy the session with `session_destroy();` @user3143168 I need to see ALL your pages/code. It's too hard for me to tell at this point what it is you're asking exactly, and where the actual problem is, with only ONE piece of code for one file.

Comment: OK, see my **EDIT** under the HTML form, I added some code that will destroy the previous session, if one exists, for example: `Bear`. @user3143168

Comment: The problem is a computer store too many website. All the website are using $_SESSION['user'] to save user id When user already was login. How to avoid when i login A website, The B website also was login too.

Comment: My new code will fix that. Did you try it or not? @user3143168 and use the HTML form I posted in my EDIT. It is Important.

Comment: You want to avoid people seeing `B` page if the session is NOT set, is that what you're trying to tell me? @user3143168 I'm sorry but I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean.

Comment: Sorry it is not easy to express.
Yup, that i want to say. When user login in A page and $_SESSION['user'] is set. The B page was login if using same session

Comment: See **EDIT #2** on top of my answer. If this doesn't work, I don't know how else I can. @user3143168

Answer (score 0):

Session is maintained with the browser. When one user has logged in with the browser the other user cannot login with the same browser. Because the browser is already running one session.If u try to login it gives you the current session which is running. For that reason you get Welcome Bear when to try to login with `Account B`, whereas `Account A` is already logged in. Take an Example of `Gmail` you cannot login two `Gmail` accounts on the same browser simultanioulsy. So Better use different browser while logging with two accounts.
`use Diffrent Browser.`

Comment: Haven't you seen `Add account` option in Gmail after log in? That enables you to log into multiple Gmail account in same browser.

Comment: They have an another way to handle the sessions. But by normal programming this is the best way.Go to gmail and login with one account then add another account and login. Now you have two accounts logged in. Now open newtab and enter gmail.com. See which account opens. The Account which you logged first open.

Comment: Thank you! i may say that if Gmail have Gmail_A and Gmail_B in same the server Gmail_A and Gmail_B program are the same. But they have difference Database. So how to avoid When user login the Gamil_A, user also was login in Gmail_B.

Comment: use different browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named sessions to achieve this, though it isn't full-proof since it relies on a `GET` variable. Here is an example of how you could implement using a get variable `userName`

```
if($_GET['userName']) {

    session_name($_GET['userName']);

}

session_start();
```

Since [`session_name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) gets or sets a named session, depending on whether it already exists, the above would work as long as the session identifier is passed in with the request. If the URL is modified and the request is made without the identifier, you would want to handle that as you see fit (destroy any existing sessions and start a fresh one, fallback to session based on cookie, etc).

Also, I would imagine that having the actual session name be "bob123" might be a security risk, since it would be much easier to steal someone's session if you know it's always their user name, so you should research recommendations for how to reduce this risk.